# How can I reapply to a company that I rejected once?

Tags: job-search, united-states, applications

A few months ago I had received several job offers, and decided to go with a 2 month contract role, while rejecting the other full-time/W2 roles.

Now that the contract is ending, I noticed that one of the companies I had received an offer from is hiring again for the same role. What is the proper way to politely ask to be considered for the role?

Should I reach out to the contact (manager who oversees the department/interviewed me) I have at the job or should I apply directly to the position online? If its the former, what would be a polite way to ask to be considered for the role?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere although related questions, this one is asking if an email should be sent *additional to* the online application process, as some sort of vantage point. The dupe you linked is asking about how to word (and if worth sending) email to both HR and his manager-to-be (no online form).  Also, in this case the rejected company *is* hiring, and in the dupe the OP indicates it is not sure if they are hiring.

Answer (score 0):

> Should I reach out to the contact [...] I have at the job or should I apply directly to the position online?

Just apply online or using the official means for that purpose. Skipping the process and reaching out to the manager who interviewed you might be seen as you trying to use your contacts to land the job.

Let the hiring process go through its natural way, and if you are a good candidate (most surely, as you were already offered a job) you might get the job.

If you *really* feel it necessary, you can write an email to you contact *after* applying online, telling him that you applied again and are looking forward to the opportunity and any follow-up needed. However I would refrain from sending that email at all.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you consider reaching out directly to that interviewer? Did he ever say it is ok for you to reach out to him directly?
Why do you expect he will even remember you? Do you know that he interviews very few people or did you solve for him some very important problem and you stood out from all candidates by far?
Unless the answer to any of these questions is yes you should reapply.
Most organized companies keep records of previous candidates so your previous performance should be taken into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

I think, If you are confident and have faith in employer, contact them and tell them what do you want. If they will find you good enough,will offer you the position again without wasting time. (Head hunting approach). Otherwise, you should needs to reapply for advertised post and mentioned them in email about your previous experience( interview and rejection) and explain them why your are interested in advertised position now. Prepared yourself this time better than before so that they will consider you as best candidate again.